# wpf and entity framework navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

in my Project i use entity framework with navigation,

I have 3 tables in the model

```
1. Person
2. Family
3. Folder
```

in the Folder table i have navigation  family_Id
in the Family i have navigation  person_Id

in the code I wrote this

```
var load = mh.Folder.Include("family_Id");
```

then i know all family Columns
now i want to know the Person_Name from Person table 
how can i include the person table?

the Person table is not navigation to Folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entities are all related with navigation proprties, you can do:

```
var load = mh.Folder.Include("Family").Include("Family.Person");
```